# Sort Array through scanf

Tags: c, arrays

so I've managed to sort my array-values through hard-coding them in.
but every now and then i want to manually add new values through scanf.
For some reason it doesn't work.
here's the code:

```
int main(void) {
   int tal[5];
   int temp, i, j;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
      scanf("%d",&tal[i]);
    }
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(j=0;j<5;j++){
         if(tal[j] < tal[i]){
            temp = tal[j];
            tal[i] = tal[j];
            tal[j] = temp;
         }
      }   
   }
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
      printf("%d\n",tal[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

eg. Input: `3 6 5 7 8`
Output: `3 3 3 3 3`

Where is my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your swapping.

```
if(tal[j] < tal[i]){
        temp = tal[j];      //put tal[j] in temp
        tal[i] = tal[j];    // put tal[j] in tal[i], (tal[i] value lost)
        tal[j] = temp;      // put temp in tal[j], 
    }
```

It should be,

```
if(tal[j] < tal[i]){
        temp = tal[j];
        tal[j] = tal[i];
        tal[i] = temp;
    }
```